# How were the diffusion statistics for norx calculated?

Tags: statistical-test, diffusion

I was reading the norx specification and came across [this section](https://norx.io/data/norx.pdf#table.caption.23), which provides some kind of statistics about the diffusion of the norx round function. However, I don't see how these values were calculated or what they really mean.

If I could also find out how the diffusion was visualized in the figure following the statistics, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe they posted the source code for their diffusion calculator

Comment: @RichieFrame Do you have more information then that? I don't see mention of that in the pdf I linked to, or anything like it in in their master.zip source file from their website.

Comment: https://github.com/norx/node

Comment: that one actually may only be the differential search engine, for some reason I thought it also processed the diffusion data

Comment: The vis looks like a monochrome bitmap that was set to black for 1 and white for 0, then grayscaled, blurred, resized, and recolored

Comment: @RichieFrame I want to ask about the "black for 1 and white for 0" part, but with that level of detail you might as well post an answer. But in case you're not so inclined, are these bits simply the bits of the block being displayed this way at each stage of processing?

Comment: If I was sure I would post an answer, as well as a method to replicate it. I believe they are indeed simply the bits of the block, their min/max/averages are probably with several test keys and nonces